# How to make a variable to be visible across tabs when using google chrome developer console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a script that I usually execute across my opened tabs on  *chrome developer console.*

Some of my variables are common to all the tabs.

**So how can I make a variable to be visible across the tabs**, *so I can share the common ones*?

Comment: Impossible. Each tab is sandboxed independently.

Comment: you can use localStorage, if all your sites are in the same domain

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr thanks fro the info.

Comment: Thanks @surajck but the sites are on d/t domain. I appreciate the hint though

Answer (score 2):

You can use any [HTML5 storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), I recommended use `sessionStorage`/`localStorage`. Then any key changed in `sessionStorage`/`localStorage` it fire `Storage` event for all tabs in same domain.

Add handler to storage:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);
} else {
  window.attachEvent("onstorage", handle_storage);
};
```

In this `handle_storage` we will listen for example `global_storage_vars` key to know what vars are shared. `Storage` event fire for all browser tabs:

```
function handle_storage(e){
    e = e || window.event;

    //key that changed  e.key;
    //old value         e.oldValue;
    //new value         e.newValue;
    
    if (e && e.key === 'global_storage_vars') {
        console.log('The global vars changed to:', e.newValue);
        //here you can get a needed shared variable and do what you want
    }   
}
```

**Example**:

First tab - http://fiddle.jshell.net/r8dy8rf7/show/light/

Second tab - http://fiddle.jshell.net/nL7cq9xu/show/light/

Run in first tab console `localStorage.setItem('global_storage_vars', {a : 1})` and check second tab.

## Access across all tabs with different domains:

You can make a Chrome Extension and it can has access to all tabs.

Comment: upvoted you because I did not know this feature too; it could also help other users looking for this **but it does not answer my question**.

Comment: Have you tried it from `console` ? I create a 2 fiddles: http://fiddle.jshell.net/r8dy8rf7/show/light/ and http://fiddle.jshell.net/nL7cq9xu/show/light/ and run in console `localStorage.setItem('global_storage_vars', {a : 1})`. All works

Comment: because you are under _same domain_ `fiddle.jshell.net`

Comment: Ok, I undestand, I suppose that meen the same domain. You can make a Chrome Extension and it can has access to all tabs.